# Filter out camera or album in Mac Photos

Tags: macos, photos

I import photos from my daughter's camera into the Photos app, along with (many more of) my own. I created a Smart Album for her camera type so that all of her photos wind up in a separate album. I would like to hide those photos from the main "Photos" view. If there were a feature to either filter by camera type, or filter out all photos that are contained in a certain album, that would work, but I can't find a feature like that.

I am aware of the ability to hide photos but I would like something that is "smart" or automatic rather than requiring me to manually hide photos each time I import new ones.

Suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Best would have been not to mix them in the first place - make an account for each user. You can't filter out from the main lib, only filter into smart folders.

Comment: A new iCloud account you mean, @Tetsujin?

Comment: Mac user account - that way the two libraries would always be separate. iCloud too, but only if you also share over iCloud.

Comment: Makes sense. If you write it up as an answer I'll accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a lot harder to filter out from a single library without manually copying each source to separate Albums etc.

I'd suggest long-term it would be considerably simpler to not merge them in the first place.

This is achievable in two ways...

1. Use separate Libraries on the same user account.
   Downside is you have to remember to launch Photos with the correct library each time.
2. Use separate Mac User accounts.
   You still need remember to swap for each user, but the swap is quick & could be aided by using distinct desktop images to make remembering which is which easier.
   Additionally, once this method is set up each camera could be told not to automatically load images to the 'wrong' library. You can use Image Capture to set this behaviour, per device, per user account - see my answer on https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/214282/85275

You'd have to set up the initial swap manually in both cases. Drag all one user's pictures to a new folder in a shared location & use that to create a new library. Delete the originals once you're happy it all worked correctly.